# webkit adding additional <a> tags in <li>

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have a code snippet as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home<a></li>
            <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li><li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>      
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

webkit based browsers are displaying these as

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home<a><a></a></li>
            <li><a></a><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li><li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>       
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Notice the additional empty anchor tags. I have some javascript logic that iterates over these li tags and fix the anchors, but now that goes for a toss because of the spurious anchor tags. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: If I remove the new line between the fist <li> and second <li> then one of the spurious <a> elements vanish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li><a href="home.html">Home<a></li>
```

isn't it supposed to be

```
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might just have a typo. In this chunk of code:

```
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home<a></li>
        <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li><li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>      
      </ul>
    </div>
```

It looks like the last `<a>` tag in  `<a href="home.html">Home<a>` needs to be closed. So when Webkit comes across that last `<a>` it opens and closes it for you.

Give this a try:

```
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>      
      </ul>
    </div>
```